# Vue.Draggable not letting me move items between lists

Tags: vue.js, drag-and-drop

Trying to follow [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@john.pickett/vue-draggable-drop-and-drop-sorting-for-vue-js-100222dcff65), but with bi-directional dragging between containers.  Reducing the problem to the minimal set of code, I'm able to sort within a list but not between lists.  I was under the impression from the documentation that setting both draggables to the same group name would enable it, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

So, what do I need to do in order to just allow items to be moved from one list to another?  Here's the code I've tried (which, again, does perfectly for rearranging within the same list)

```
<template>
<v-container fill-height fluid grid-list-md mt-0 class='about'>
    <v-layout column fill-height>
      <h1>This is an about page</h1>
      <v-layout row fill-height>
        <v-flex xs4>
          <draggable class='dragArea' v-model='peopleList'>
            <div v-for='person in peopleList' :key='person.id' :options='{group: "people"}'>{{ person.name }}</div>
          </draggable>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex xs4>
          <draggable class='dragArea' v-model='employeeList'>
            <div v-for='person in employeeList' :key='person.id' :options='{group: "people"}'>{{ person.name }}</div>
          </draggable>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-layout>
</v-container>
</template>
<script>
import draggable from 'vuedraggable'
export default {
  name: 'About',
  data () {
    return {
      employees: [{ id: 6, name: 'Pete' },
        { id: 7, name: 'Pat' }],
      people: [
        { id: 1, name: 'Bob' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Mary' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Jane' },
        { id: 4, name: 'Alex' },
        { id: 5, name: 'Jim' }
      ]
    }
  },
  components: { draggable },
  computed: {
    employeeList: {
      get () {
        return this.employees
      },
      set (value) {
        this.employees = value
      }
    },
    peopleList: {
      get () {
        return this.people
      },
      set (value) {
        this.people = value
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
<style>
div.dragArea {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 100px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `options` parameter applies to the `draggable` component, not to the children of that element. If you add `options` to `draggable` it works as you expect.

```
<draggable class='dragArea' v-model='peopleList' :options='{group: "people"}'>
  <div v-for='person in peopleList' :key='person.id'>{{ person.name }}</div>
</draggable>
```

Comment: Damn, don't know how I missed that! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 6):

The syntax changed in 2.20. You're supposed to use `group="<name>"` attribute now:

```
    <draggable class="dragArea" v-model="peopleList" group="people">
      <div v-for="person in peopleList" :key="person.id">{{ person.name }}</div>
    </draggable>
```